# «Даёшь молодёжь!» — запятая нужна?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, лексика, значение-слов

«Даёшь молодёжь!» Запятая нужна или нет? Не думаю, что «молодежь» — это обращение...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

То есть здесь смысл: *мы требуем молодёжь!*
Так полагаю, что происходит от: *дай (что?) молодёжь* (поэтому запятая не нужна). Настоящее время, вероятно, для того, чтобы ускорить процесс: уже сейчас даёшь, или будут проблемы.

Не путать с: *во даёшь, молодёжь* (удивление, а не требование).

Answer (score 2):

Правильно думаете. Если это призыв, лозунг, движение, то запятая здесь не нужна.
[**давать**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
**6.** ◊ **Даёшь!** В первые годы Советской власти: призыв к осуществлению, преодолению чего-либо. *Даёшь стометровку! Даёшь миллион кубометров дров.*

Даёшь молодёжь!
Даёшь Днепрогэс! Даёшь пятилетку в четыре года! Даёшь БАМ!

*Плакат удался в самом деле,

мне были как раз по нутру

на фоне тайги и метели

два слова: **«Даешь Ангару!»***
Ярослав Смеляков. Даёшь! (1957)

P. S. Вот [здесь](https://radiosputnik.ria.ru/20191222/1562696022.html) еще есть информация.
***«Даешь молодежь!».*** — точка после кавычек не нужна.